# Flutter IOS app not receiving FCM notifications when deployed to test flight

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a flutter app that i am trying to get Firebase cloud messaging to work on but for some reason it refuses to work when deploying to test flight.

If i run in debug mode through VSCode everything works as it should but as soon as i run `flutter build ios` and deploy to test flight everything breaks.

I have tried a multitude of solutions over the past couple of days including:

- Removing and re-adding all certs & provisioning profiles
- changing  `<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key><false/>` to `<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key><string>0<string/>` AND to `<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key><string>NO<string/>`
- trying to force the APNS token to be a production token by adding this to

  `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) { #if DEVELOPMENT //Develop Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken as Data, type: .sandbox) #else //Production Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken as Data, type: .prod) #endif }`

I have also tried doing different combinations of the above in the hope that one of the solutions would work in tandem with each other.

if anyone can shed some light on why this might be happening i would be extremely grateful!

Comment: I would like to know something more about this problem. I have the exact same issue. Notifications are working with the ios device attached to a USB cable, but when I deploy the app to test flight, nothing happens! I've also tried to solve this problem by modifying the AppDelegate in many ways but with no luck. Let me know if you have found a solution, thanks

Comment: In my case in firebase console I had uploaded APNs Certificate (.p12), which was not working on TestFlight, so I created APNs Key (.p8) in apple developer account, downloaded it and uploaded to Firebase, after that it started working